# Вызов события если сгенерировано нужное число, ошибка Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

Изучая тему событий, задумал себе задачку: если сгенерировано заданное число, то вызвать событие. Определяю код, который будет заниматься генерацией чисел:

```
delegate void RightNumber(object sendler, EventArguments e);

class Produce
{
    public event RightNumber NumberFound;
    private int rightNumber;
    Random random = new Random();

    public Produce(int rightNumber)
    {
        this.rightNumber = rightNumber;
    }

    public void FindNumber()
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
        {
            int newValue = random.Next(10);
            if (newValue == rightNumber)
                NumberFound(this, new EventArguments(rightNumber));
        }
    }
}

class EventArguments
{
    public int rightNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return rightNumber;
        }
        private set
        {
            rightNumber = value;
        }
    }


    public EventArguments(int rightNumber)
    {
        this.rightNumber = rightNumber;
    }
}
```

И вызывающая часть программы:

```
 public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Введите задуманное число");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int rightNumber = Convert.ToInt32(str);

        Produce produce = new Produce(rightNumber);
        produce.NumberFound += DisplayResult;

        produce.FindNumber();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DisplayResult(object sendler, EventArguments e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Найдено загаданное число {e.rightNumber}");
    }
```

При выполнении программы консоль выкидывает Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException, среда указывает на этот фрагмент кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема возникает если необходимое число найдено. Пробовал делать отладку, но в виду небольшого опыта так и не смог разобраться.

Так же хотелось бы услышать комментарии по поводу стилистики кода. В целом, как его можно сделать лучше?

Comment: Проблема возникает из-за свойств. Поменял на паблик поле - работает. Что я не так написал? Стараюсь придерживаться инкапсуляции, поэтому на мой взгляд использование свойства тут обязательно. Как будет выглядеть корректный код с использованием свойств?

Comment: Попробуйте порассуждать, что делает код в `set` для `rightNumber` (да и в `get` тоже). Заодно можно посмотреть, как объявляют свойства в классах (на MSDN, например). P.S. Подсказка: StackOverflowException обычно возникает при бесконечной рекурсии.

Comment: @ixSci  я не знал что это рекурсия)

Comment: @АлексейФедотов а что же это ещё, когда свойство ссылается на само себя?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov все равно не понимаю. Свойство же такое же поле, с геттером и сеттером и возможностью задавать параметры доступа к отдельному акцессору + проверка значений. Я действительно не понимаю почему проваливаюсь в рекурсию

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я произвожу отладку, проваливаюсь в конструктор, и потом идет выполнение свойства. Почему вообще происходит выполнение свойства?

Comment: исправьте public int rightNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return rightNumber;
        }
        private set
        {
            rightNumber = value;
        }
    }
на
public int rightNumber { get;    private set;}

Comment: @VladimirT код работает, спасибо. Но мне по прежнему нужна помощь. Почему мой вариант не работает?  обычный код для геттера, ничего не обычного, видел в других примерах. Для сеттера тоже. В чем проблема то? разве ваша запись делает не одно и тоже?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов нет, это совершенно разные вещи. Посмотрите в ответ, надеюсь, расписал более или менее понятно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, давайте разберемся в Вашей проблеме:
Для начала Вам было бы неплохо узнать, что есть [StackOverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Исключение, которое выбрасывается при переполнении стека выполнения
>   из-за чрезмерного количества вложенных вызовов метода

Обычно появление данного исключения обусловлено бесконечной [рекурсией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), которая затаилась в Вашем коде (к слову, данное исключение может появляться не только при ошибочном зацикливании кода, но и, как сказано выше, в виду чрезмерной вложенности вызовов определенного рекурсивного метода)

---

Где же спряталась рекурсия в Вашем коде? Собственно, `Visual Studio` явно указала Вам на это место:

```
public int rightNumber
{
    get
    {
        return rightNumber;
    }
    private set
    {
        rightNumber = value;
    }
}
```

Что не так с этим кодом? Давайте взглянем: 
Начнем с `get`:
Вы в `return` указали то же самое свойство, которое его и вызывает, то есть `rightNumber`. Тем самым, получается такая картина:

```
int x = rightNumber; // вызывается return rightNumber внутри rightNumber->get
    return rightNumber; // снова вызывается return rightNumber внутри rightNumber->get 
        return rightNumber; // и снова вызывается return rightNumber внутри rightNumber->get 
            return rightNumber; // и опять вызывается return rightNumber внутри rightNumber->get 
                ...
```

И так до бесконечности. Свойство рекурсивно ссылается на само себя. Так что значение никогда не будет получено, ибо в попытках получить его, мы заходим в геттер нашего свойства, который возвращает значение `rightNumber`, а чтобы получить его значение, мы снова лезем в его геттер и так далее
Продолжим с `set`, в котором и выползла Ваша ошибка:
И вновь вы указали, что самому же свойству `rightNumber` присваивается `value`. То есть в данном случае аналогично примеру выше Вы рекурсивно вызываете `rightNumber->set`:

```
rightNumber = x; // вызывается rightNumber = value внутри rightNumber->set
    rightNumber = value; // снова вызывается rightNumber = value внутри rightNumber->set
        rightNumber = value; // и снова вызывается rightNumber = value внутри rightNumber->set
            rightNumber = value; // и опять вызывается rightNumber = value внутри rightNumber->set
                ...
```

И опять же идет сие до бесконечности. Ибо свойство снова таки ссылается на само себя

---

Как решить проблему? Очень просто: Вам необходимо заменить определение Вашего свойства на

```
public int rightNumber { get; private set; }
```

или на

```
public int rightNumber
{
    get
    {
        return _rightNumber;
    }
    private set
    {
        _rightNumber = value;
    }
}
private int _rightNumber;
```

В первом случае Вы воспользуетесь так называемыми [автоматически реализуемыми свойствами](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) (условно, то, что описано во втором варианте, будет реализовано автоматически и спрятано от глаз Ваших. Обнаружить созданные `backingField`'s Вы сможете с помощью [рефлексии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#C#))

---

Надеюсь, что мой ответ смог Вам помочь, а так же, что Вы разберетесь в допущенной ошибке и больше никогда ее не повторите)
Успехов в Ваших начинаниях!